# Constrain 'pickable' attributes after picks in pick function (TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, function

I created the following util function within my codebase:

```
const pick = <T extends object, P extends keyof T, R = Pick<T,P>>(
obj: T,
keys: P[]
): R => {
if (!obj) return {} as R
return keys.reduce((acc, key) => {
   return {...acc, [key]:obj[key] };
}, {} as R)
};
```

The function works fine and TS infers the correct return type. Only issue is the keys parameter, I want to constrain it based on the previous chosen keys.

Example:

```
const obj = {name: 'John Doe', age: '33', city: 'NYC'} 

// When typing the keys in the keys array param, it infers the keys correctly
const a = pick(obj, ['name', 'age']) 

// BUT, this is also possible, and TS doesnt complain
const b = pick(obj, ['name', 'age', 'age']) 

// ALSO, when I have already entered for example 'name', I want intellisense only to show 'age' and 'city' as possible options, currently it still shows all keys.
```

I tried many things (even currying the function), but with no success, its proven to be a tough TS puzzle. I hope I can get some help!

Comment: Your `R` type parameter is superfluous and should probably be replaced with `Pick<T, P>` for the purposes of your question... even if you want to use generic defaults as shorthand it's probably out of scope for the question as asked.

Comment: Can you explain why you care about this?  Does something go wrong with `pick(obj, ["name", "age", "age"])`?  Is the output unexpected in some way?

Comment: Note that you can kind of get the behavior you want, as shown in [this playground example](https://tsplay.dev/N9P83w), but it's pretty complicated for what seems like questionable benefit.  I can write that solution up as an answer if you want.... unless there's something about it that doesn't work for you. Let me know.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for your answer, its definitely closer to what I want. Only thing left is the intellisense, you can see it here: [LINK](https://imgur.com/a/L1S39nh), name is already picked, so it should not be an option. So for the next pickable keys I want to only see: [age, city]. I know its overkill, the output is not unexpected, but I like the intellisense to be a reflection of what is still possible, instead of all possibilities. If that makes any sense. I would much like a write up of your solution. I highly appreciate the effort. This gave me a lot of headache

Comment: I don't think it's possible to get the IntelliSense autocomplete prompting to do what you want because as far as I know, it gets that list from the constraint `K extends Array<keyof T>`... the constraint would have to be `K extends ExcludeArray<keyof T, K>` to give you that IntelliSense, but that constraint is illegally circular.  Do you still want the answer written up or is the IntelliSense prompting more important?

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for the answer, I would still appreciate the answer written up :)

Comment: Okay I will write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't natively support the concept of a "unique" array where no elements are duplicated.  So there's no simple way to write `keys: UniqueArray<P>`.

Instead you could try to build a complicated [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) and [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) type that acts like a constraint on the [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) you pass in for `keys`, where each element type [excludes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) all previous element types.  So if you pass in an array of type `K extends Array<keyof T>`, the compiler will make sure that `K` is assignable to `ExcludeArray<keyof T, K>` and complain if it doesn't.

It could look like this:

```
type ExcludeArray<T, U extends any[], A extends any[] = []> =
    number extends U['length'] ? [...T[]] : (
        U extends [infer F, ...infer R] ?
        ExcludeArray<Exclude<T, F>, R, [...A, F extends T ? F : T]> : A
    );

function pick<T extends object, K extends Array<keyof T>>(
    obj: T,
    keys: [...K] extends ExcludeArray<keyof T, K> ? K : ExcludeArray<keyof T, K>
): Pick<T, K[number]>;
function pick(obj: any, keys: PropertyKey[]) {
    if (!obj) return {}
    return keys.reduce((acc, key) => {
        return { ...acc, [key]: obj[key] };
    }, {})
};
```

The `ExcludeArray<T, U>` type takes a type `T` and a tuple type `U` and walks through `U` building a version of it where each element excludes all previous elements:

```
type Example1 = ExcludeArray<1 | 2 | 3 | 4, [1, 2, 3, 4]> 
// type Example1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
type Example2 = ExcludeArray<1 | 2 | 3 | 4, [1, 2, 2, 4]> 
// type Example2 = [1, 2, 3 | 4, 4]
```

So `Example1` is the same as the `U` passed in, because there are no duplicates.  But `Example2` shows that the third element has been changed from `2` (a duplicate) to `3 | 4` (the allowable values at that point).

Note that in a perfect world we could have written `pick()` like

```
function pick<T extends object, K extends ExcludeArray<keyof T, K>>(
  obj: T, keys: K
): Pick<T, K[number]> {...}
```

but the constraint `K extends ExcludeArray<keyof T, K>>` is illegally circular.  Instead we need to jump through hoops where `K extends Array<keyof T>` at declaration and then we convince the compiler to treat `K` as if it were so constrained at the use site, hence `keys: [...K] extends ExcludeArray<keyof T, K> ? K : ExcludeArray<keyof T, K>`.

---

Anyway, let's test it:

```
const obj = { name: 'John Doe', age: '33', city: 'NYC' }

const a = pick(obj, ['name', 'age']); // okay
const b = pick(obj, ['name', 'age', 'age']); // error!  
// -------------------------------> ~~~~~
// Type '"age"' is not assignable to type '"city"'
const c = pick(obj, ["name", "age", "ss"])
// -------------------------------> ~~~~
// Type '"ss"' is not assignable to type '"name" | "age" | "city"'
```

This behaves as desired.

---

Unfortunately, as you note, you don't get the autocomplete prompting behavior from IntelliSense.  When you are in the middle of calling `pick()`, the prompted values will be the full set of keys, even the ones you've already used:

```
const d = pick(obj, ["age", ""]) 
// ------------------------> ^^ <-- prompted with "age", "city", "name"
```

So you can choose a repeat and then the compiler will complain.

There's nothing much I can do about this.  IntelliSense only uses the constraint `Array<keyof T>` for its prompting, and it does not try to evaluate `ExcludeArray<keyof T, K>`, nor can it do so easily, since your mid-development string literal is unlikely to be one of the proper values so the inference fails anyway.  This is essentially beyond the capabilities of the compiler.

---

So above I present a complicated solution which behaves mostly the way you want but doesn't have great IntelliSense support.  You may want to consider the alternative... that is, just accept `Array<keyof T>` with possible repeats. After all, the value and type that comes out of `pick()` will still be correct.  The problem with `["name", "age", "age"]` is that the last `"age"` is *unnecessary*; it's not *harmful* in any way.  Since the consequences for allowing repeats are so minor, I'd say that the cure is worse than the disease in this case.  But of course that's up to you.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-Hkg1XE8So4G6gzfDfmb5BbfQU+7JdwAVFAMMg8LWoBSqTT6Yy-eyDUEoEq+cBBcKFmKB0CmdaUA1leMeRVLtNU8AUvXTd8AyDdQtGwG5LzuMkEHpJhgG-Hl5iLFRJggTwjAAKVpSwGQAEVpCAjHIPAzDIqAjF2XYmKgBAQlAciADkAE0AGEjD3bDcPwvB5ljFlIO5aojHoUjuKMFjGK4U95Bw+g8KgDRZL9BSlJUtRGPIdTWLUjSbEGKAHmoXBaWwCslExKAAFpvJ83y-P8gKfJkAA-ULQo84ggXYgAiDTovEkIWHoWlpKYJgQjMFSNFMJ5aSeKKjGi3jQHihRdP0hAjLjJVqmisyIGi8hYtYxqoGitLoq0jzAp63rfJCsKIoK9qmHiqBEpUFLWDSjKspy4A8uxQr6uig5moatbipAUr5EkvT8LQKr5JqyR1ta6LAF4NwAxHc6wtur6h6ZAAPSeqBCG8xlMymOhDoAdz4yw2ripqtvOlagA)

Comment: Amazing, thank you very much! I do understand that still being able to pick 'age' is technically correct and still possible. But it feels 'wrong', though I am just nitpicking so I do understand your pragmatic solution and implementation.